# different passwords depending on plugged-in devices

Tags: linux, login, password, udev, pam

I would like to have different passwords for my account(s): When (e.g.) a certain USB stick is plugged in then an easy password is to be used. The idea is: If I leave my computer then I take the stick with me and the easy passwords shall be disabled then.

My general idea is:

1. Detect the stick with udev, maybe detect certain data on it (with a script run by udev) and react accordingly (e.g. create a file which is deleted when the stick is plugged out). This should be easy.
2. Have PAM check for the existence of this file and select the password database accordingly.

The main question is probably (i.e. if I understand the structure of the problem correctly): Can `pam_unix2` be configured to use another shadow file? I just had a look at the man page for `pam_unix2` and it seems that this is not possible because this module lets glibc NSS make this decision.

Comment: This seems very plausible to me. I would expect it may be completely done just with PAM modules and nothing more. There are conditionals in PAM that would allow for checks to be skipped over if certain criteria weren't met.

Comment: This looks like what you're asking for: https://www.suse.com/communities/conversations/pam-pluggable-authentication-module-usb-authentication/

Comment: @slm Interesting but this is about replacing password authentication not about modifying it, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both pam_unix and pam_unix2 use libc to look up the password hash, and Glibc has the locations `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and `/etc/shadow` hard-coded. It wouldn't even be as simple as recompiling `pam_unix` or `pam_unix2`: both go through the normal NSS mechanism to verify passwords, they only use their knowledge of `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow` and NIS for password changes.

However, you can use the [`pam_pwdfile` module](https://github.com/tiwe-de/libpam-pwdfile). I've never used it, but the description looks like exactly what you're after.

> This PAM module lets you use an arbitrarily-named text file similar in
>    structure to `/etc/passwd` to authenticate users.

Alternatively, you could use the [`pam_userdb`](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_userdb.html), which checks a password in a database in Berkeley DB format with a file name passed as an argument.

Now, to detect the presence of the USB stick, you need another PAM module. [`pam_listfile`](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_listfile.html) looks right for the job. Arrange an udev rule that mounts your USB key, and only that USB key, in a particular location, say `/media/authentication-key`; create a file `users.txt` containing the list of user names that are allowed to use a shorter password. If you want a more complex test in the PAM stack, you can use [`pam_exec](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_exec.html).

Here's a stack that assumes that `/etc/shadow` contains your strong passwords and `/etc/passwd.weak` contains your weak passwords. Warning: untested, and I'm not fluent in PAM, so review it carefully.

```
auth [success=ignore default=1] pam_listfile.so file=/media/authentication-key/users.txt iter=user sense=allow onerr=fail
auth [success=1 default=bad] pam_unix.so
auth [success=ok default=bad] pam_pwdfile.so pwdfile=/etc/passwd.weak
auth requisite pam_deny.so
```

Answer (score 1):

It just came to my mind that the difficult part I had in mind could be replaced by a very simple operation:

It is probably not necessary to configure PAM to use either one password file or the other: It should be possible to just replace `/etc/shadow` by a symlink and have the script which it triggered by the udev add and remove events to replace this symlink so that the normal PAM procedure (implicitly) uses the one or the other version of the file.

This way some accounts can be prevented from logins completely without the hardware token.

Comment: This may be a solution but if you have better ideas I am interested. :-)

Comment: I like your question: but if you do so you will change it for all the users. And this will work for each kind (even remote) of login :-S

Comment: One other idea would be to write a `/etc/profile.d` script that checks for the existence of a filesystem with the UUID that's on the USB stick. If it's present it just exits normally, if it isn't it could prompt for a second harder password. If the password fails, then the user is logged out with a `fuser -k $(tty)` or something to that effect.

Comment: There's also potential for data coherency problems if you have two different shadow file copies. Especially as users are added or removed.

Comment: @Hastur Remote logins with passwords? :-)  But you are right: A real PAM solution would be better.

Comment: @JoelDavis That's not going to work with X logins or screensaver password protection. The data coherency problem must be handeled no matter if you have a simple symlink or a sophisticated PAM switch solution. The files could be checked on every switching for changes. New lines could simply be copied, old ones be deleted.

Comment: For screensaver logins, can't you assume that if a user was once logged in that another user who knows the simpler password is likely the same user? You should be able to prompt a GUI user using something like `zenity` in a [login script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247706/start-script-when-gnome-starts-up), attempt to authenticate, failing authentication, you can send a `SIGHUP` to their Xorg PID which should kick them back to the login screen.

Comment: There shouldn't be any data coherency problems with this approach since we're not modifying or duplicating data sources. This approach is basically going away from your "swap data sources as appropriate" approach and goes towards having the impact of the USB stick be handled in an if/else statement. Each user runs the same script no matter what, only the application behavior changes.

Comment: Basically, I'm just saying that I think this is easier to handle with login scripts rather than modifying files or the data contained therein.

Comment: I don't know if you've already looked into this but [there looks to be a pam_usb](https://github.com/aluzzardi/pam_usb) module.

Comment: @JoelDavis slm pointed to the USB PAM module in his comment to the question. And no, as this is about additional protection it does not make sense to me to assume that someone who knows the easy password is entitled to access the system.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you write a *shadow-easy* password file with the device UUID that authorizes the substitutions for password, the username, the *Not easy password* and *easy password* encrypted.

This only for the users that require easy-password.

It's possible to think about a substitution of the encrypted string only for that specific line on the `etc/shadow`. Only when an authorized device (with some data....) is plugged in.

When you add/remove users or modify password the 2 encrypted strings will not match and the substitution will not happen. So you need to log with the full password, and after to act in other way.

I don't want to think what can happens when there is a shortage of power when you touch shadow file, or if the script crashes...

It remains the problem that it will function for all the kinds of login even remote. And even if someone will send commands via ssh. But it can function :)